# Does Babylon's wonder count for scientific structure victory points?

Tags: 7-wonders

In 7 Wonders, do the science symbols on Babylon's wonder mat count for victory points? Say I've built the second level of the A side and I have no other science symbols. Do I get one point for each of the three symbols and seven for the 1 set of three symbols?

Comment: Regarding your question about the "set of three", as a general rule any card with yellow `/` between the symbols means you choose ONE of them, you don't get all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Babylon's A second stage (or B's third stage) allows you to get **one** scientific symbol of your choice at the end of the game, if you have built it. If you do, it counts for the scientific points. It works exactly like the Scientific purple card "Scientists' Guild".

Example: you have 4 "Gear" green cards and build Babylon's 2nd stage. You can convert it to a 5th "Gear" at the end of the game and earn a total of 25 points for 5 *same* green cards.

Comment: Is this specified in the rules? I found them slightly unclear.

Comment: Yes. Page 8: "*The Hanging Gardens of Babylon; at the end of the game, the player gains an extra scientific symbol of their choice. Clarification : the choice of symbol is made at the end of the game, when counting victory points, and not when this stage of the Wonder is built.*"